# Как в функции на языке Си отследить тот факт, что был передан аргумент, лежащий вне задекларированного (uint64_t) диапазона?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void simple(uint64_t x)
{
  unsigned long long t = (unsigned long long) x;

  if(t > (unsigned long long) UINT64_MAX) 
  {
     printf("Out, x = %" PRIu64 "\n", x);
  }
  else 
  {
     printf("In, x = 0x%llx\n", x);
  }
}

int main()
{
  simple(UINT64_MAX);   // x = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
  simple(UINT64_MAX+2); // x = 0x1

  return 0;  
}
```

Как в функции на языке Си **отследить тот факт**, что был передан аргумент, лежащий вне
задекларированного (uint64_t) диапазона?
При передаче большего числа, функция работает, но использует только младшие байты
переданного аргумента.

Comment: Добавить опций компилятору. Для gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -fanalyzer даёт хороший результат. Ещё можно динамический анализ подключить

Comment: @KoVadim у меня на показанном здесь коде gcc не ругается (ругается на printf, но вопрос не о нём)

Comment: а может потому, что в выражении UINT64_MAX+2 нет ни UB, ни "непредсказуемого поведения"? для беззнаковых типов при "переполнении" происходит вычисления по модулю. И нет никакого выхода "за диапазон".

Comment: @KoVadim да, но вычисление по модулю это видимо всё равно не то, что хочет автор вопроса

Comment: я понимаю. пока у меня нет тут хорошого предложения. Ну кроме как использовать статический анализатор.

Comment: проверил известными мне способами - для беззнаковых никто не ловит "переполнение". а для знаковых - прям сразу.  Также хочу заметить, что вот такое условие `if(t > (unsigned long long) UINT64_MAX) ` компилятор расценивает как "ну очевидно, что этого никогда не произойдет".

Comment: Так как параметр `x` имеет тип `uint64_t`, то множество его значений — целые числа из отрезка `[0; UINT64_MAX]`. Внутри функции `simple` нельзя обнаружить переполнение. Нужно проверять до того, как будет произведена арифметическая операция. Что-то вроде `if (UINT64_MAX - a < b) overflow(); else simple(a + b);`.

Comment: @wololo, наверное, это нужно в ответ перенести? Хотя вопрос странный, конечно.

Comment: Никак. Это невозможно сделать внутри функции

Comment: Как вообще можно отследить значение переменной определенного типа вне диапазона, представимого этим типом, если по определению переменная не может содержать ничего, не представимого этим типом? Как вы вообще хотите отличить единицу как переполнение и единицу, как корректное значение?...